# HOTOSM data is the same with openstreetmap.org data

Tags: openstreetmap

I extracted road networks from HOTOSM website (https://export.hotosm.org/en/v3/). I don't know whether it is the same with data used for rendering maps on openstreetmap.org

Comment: It is probably the same data since HOTOSM is based on OSM data. However only the operators of export.hotosm.org will know. Why don't you ask them? There is a mail address for contact: sysadmin@hotosm.org. Also this question is clearly offtopic for StackOverflow.

Comment: I need to extract it for a research project, so I want to know more about the process. I see there is some difference, but I don't know it is the rendering problem or the data problem.

Comment: What difference exactly and where do you see it? You can also try other [OSM extracts](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Planet.osm#Country_and_area_extracts) and compare the results.